# Excel cannot access the file when saving file

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to save my Excel file that I created in c#. I added a `DateTime.Now` to the title and made sure the characters where compatible. Now I have the above error when the folder exists. I have posted what it says could be the error but none apply. Also when I get the error it tells me the `DateTime.Now` portion is say for todays date and time started was 5/9/8E017700. That is not not a date or time for year and time. I think that maybe the problem but I am unsure as to why it is altered when I never change the variable for name. How can I get this problem resolved?

• The file name or path does not exist.

• The file is being used by another program.

• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", ".");

string filename = "IncomingProduct-" + date + ".xls";

string subPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "/Documents/Reports/";

    bool isExists = Directory.Exists(subPath);

    if (!isExists)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(subPath + filename);//error here
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(subPath + filename);
```

Comment: does  "/Documents/Reports/" exist already? Should it be  "//Documents//Reports//" in this case?

Comment: @N4TKD yes it does if it doesnt it is created.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `xlWorkBook.SaveAs` line, and examine the contents of `subPath` and `fileName`. What **exactly** are the values of those variables when your code is executed?

Comment: I would use string path = Path.combine(subPath, filename); and debug and make sure the result is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use file names with slashes so if the date has slashes it won't save it.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your help, I was searching all the internet and try to grand access to all things that I found there. At the end this was the fix!